# Module installed with cpan isn't showing up

Tags: perl, module, cpan

I'm trying to install `Array::Iterator` and `Text::ParseWords` using cpan. I'm on OSX with cpan `v1.61` and perl `v5.18.2`.

When I start up cpan, after the initial configuration, I type `install "Array::Iterator"` and it seems to install correctly. But when I try to run my perl script with `use Array::Iterator`, I get:

```
Can't locate Array/Iterator.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Array::Iterator module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at ./parse.pl line 7.
 at ./parse.pl line 7.
    main::BEGIN() called at ./parse.pl line 7
    eval {...} called at ./parse.pl line 7
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./parse.pl line 7.
 at ./parse.pl line 7.
```

Line 7 is:

```
use Array::Iterator;
```

Comment: Could be a path problem. Try print(@INC); in your code. The directory list it returns should included the location that the new module was installed into. Also, do you only have one version of perl on your box?

Answer (score 1):

Add the complete PATH where your Array::Iterator pm file is located
Use the below code in start of the script after shebang line may be the path is not loaded

BEGIN { push( @INC, 'PATH' ) }